# How can I successfully implement the .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop funkction with timer in my example below

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say I have the code below and would like to fill a dropdown dynamically like in [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicDropdown/) with [description](https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/) (the first example calls "Pulls from text files") NOT JSON or MySQL. When I choose for example "beverages" I want to wait to say 2 sec. and see the loading div container. I write, that I want to see this loading div for 2 sec. because I the practice small text files are loading very quickly, so the client doesn't see the loading div, just a flash that takes 1/3 sec. The loading container can be shown longer, for example when the connection is bad, like Wi-Fi on a restaurant. So I have the code below, but I don't know why it doesn't work and how can I declare the rule with the 2 sec.

HTML

```
<body>
 <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
  <select id="text-one">
   <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
   <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
   <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
  </select>     
<br />      
  <select id="text-two">
   <option>Please choose from above</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text-one").change(function() {
  $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
});
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>')
  .insertBefore('#text-two')
  .ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).show();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
 #loading {display:none;}
```

So when I Select from the select option "beverages" I want to see the loading div container for 2 sec. or longer, when the connection is bad or when the connection is interrupting (bad Wi-Fi). How can I improve my code above and why it didn't work. Please give me an answer, thanks.

Comment: Looks like it needs to be on the document? "As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxStart() method, must be attached to document."https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: Okay, thanks. Your idea was great - it works. But i have the problem, that the loading gif flashes on the screen. How can I show the loading gif for say 3 seconds. Do you have any idea what can I write into the .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop function that the loading bar is showing for say 3 seconds until its disapear?

Comment: There is built in throttling in chrome dev tools to simulate poor connection https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/ . You don't typically want to slow your own code down